# Stack Overflow seems to have forgotten my account

Tags: support, accounts

I have had an account on Stack Overflow for several years and had accrued some reputation points.  Today, Stack Overflow failed to recognize my account (my details are stored in a password manager, so it's not an oversight).  The "I forgot my e-mail" function says that my e-mail was not recognized.

I created a new account, but that means I lost all of my reputation an privileges.  Any suggestions?